# How do I pass a column name and a list of colum names simultaneously in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, typeerror

```
rows = ['POPESTIMATE2010',
        'POPESTIMATE2011',
        'POPESTIMATE2012',
        'POPESTIMATE2013',
        'POPESTIMATE2014',
        'POPESTIMATE2015']

df['max_rows'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(np.max(x[rows])), axis=1)

df[rows,'max_rows'].head() #TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

df['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015','max_rows'].head() #NoError
```

If I pass the names of columns then there is no error. But if I pass the list containing the names of columns there is an error.

All I want to know is that can we pass a list and a string together ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? apparently you need `df[rows + ['max_rows']]` if `rows` is `list of column names` as in your title. If rows are row indexes, then use `.loc`: `df.loc[rows, 'max_rows']`

Comment: Can you restate this question and give more complete example?  It is a bit confusing what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to know that while passing coloumns in a df , can we pass a list and a string together